# How to get CodeCommit repository from Ubuntu Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-codecommit

I'm new to AWS and I need some assistance with a quick project.

I'm trying to export some of my code located on my Ubuntu Server onto CodeCommit repository. The code lives on multiple docker containers.

Would anyone be able to provide a guide on doing so?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

CodeCommit == Git.

So if you want to "copy" from a CodeCommit repository, all you should need to do is a [git clone](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository).

EXAMPLE:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-connect.html
>
> ```
> cd /my/local/directory
> git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/MyDemoRepo my-demo-repo
> ```

This will create a copy of your CodeCommit repo into local repository "/my/local/directory/my-demo-repo".

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is it possible to get my ecr repositories onto codecommit?

Comment: What does that even mean?